# how test separate environmental name with protractor conf js?

Tags: javascript, json, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

[[image]

The above pic i am run protractor Conf.js with particular environmental name which is stored in JSON file

how to test particular environmental URL only in the protractor test case?

Comment: How to run  protractor conf.js with particular enviralamental names from command prompt?

Comment: i need to loads protractor conf js with particular environmental URL or names  then load what is passed environmental URL ?

Comment: i don't understand the question, do you want to run protractor with arguments and then use them in the test? or do you want to use the url from the json file only in a specific place in the test?

Comment: Please help me with this problem.                                                                                                              I  have two different  URLs in my J son file and I want to pass them as parameter to run command. For ex: protractor conf js  --local

Comment: look at my answer, and see if that answers your question.

Answer (score 4):

**FIRST METHOD** - You have to pass the parameters using `params` variable in command line. Update your `conf.js` file to include a parameter called `baseUrl` and other url variables as shown below -

```
params: {
    baseUrl: "http://default_url" //provide your default url to be used
}
```

later pass the value in the command prompt. Here's how -

```
protractor conf.js --params.baseUrl 'http://www.google.com'
```

Wherever you have code to get the url in your spec's, use the following code -

```
browser.get(browser.params.baseUrl);
```

**SECOND METHOD** - If at all you don't want to pass the url to the `params` object everytime, then you can store them in your conf.js or even your specs file and call them. Here's an example -

Your `conf.js` file -

```
params: {
    baseUrl: ""
},
onPrepare: function(){
    switch(browser.params.baseUrl){
      case 'firsturl':
        browser.get("http://firsturl.com"); //replace firsturl with your actual url
        break;
      case 'secondurl':
        browser.get("http://www.secondurl.com");
        break;
      default:
        browser.get("http://www.defaulturl.com");
 }
}
```

Now pass the url's that you want to use through command line -

```
protractor conf.js --params.baseUrl 'firsturl' //to get first url
protractor conf.js //to open default url
```

**THIRD METHOD** - If at all you have a problem of running a test suite with many spec's, in that case above second method wouldn't work. You need to use `browser.get()` in each of your test spec files, in such cases use following method -

Update your conf.js file -

```
params: {
    baseUrl: "",
    url: ""
},
onPrepare: function(){
    switch(browser.params.baseUrl){
      case 'firsturl':
        browser.params.url = "http://firsturl.com"; //replace firsturl with your actual url
        break;
      case 'secondurl':
        browser.params.url = "http://www.secondurl.com";
        break;
      default:
        browser.params.url = "http://www.defaulturl.com";
 }
}
```

Your command line commands -

```
protractor conf.js --params.baseUrl 'firsturl' //to get first url
protractor conf.js //to open default url
```

Your test spec files need to include the `browser.get()` command. Here's how -

```
browser.get(browser.params.url);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank for given your suggestion I try it but not working

Comment: can you sce this image [1]:HTTP://i.stack.imgur.com/NzRTE.png

Comment: The use of params like this is well documented and the correct way to do this.

Comment: thank for your suggestion  Girish Sortur and i have one question                                  when run test case as per your scenario exactly but  when run test case it pass  string name not URL ?

Comment: For **first method** pass the url directly from command line. For **second method** pass the string in the command line that has the url in conf.js switch statement as shown above.

Comment: for second method pass the string name in switch statements in conf,js

Comment: Yes, pass the string name that is present in the case statements - `firsturl` and `secondurl`. If you don't provide any url and just run `protractor conf.js` it opens the `defaulturl`. Isn't it clear for you yet?

Comment: I follow your scenario second method when run protractor conf.js with my test case ?when run conf js with switch name in command prompt it pass only string name?

Comment: what you said yes current but this string name firsturl and secondurl passed in test case then I try print on console it prints only "firsturl" and "secondurl" only it does not pass url on test case?

Comment: Did you replace the url's with the url that you want to open - `"http://firsturl.com"` change this to the url that you want to open also change the second one too.

Comment: yes i replace with URL but that URL or name not passed to next test case?

Comment: What do you mean next test case? Are you running a suite of test spec's together? If yes then all you can do is use `browser.get()` in each of your test spec's. Updated answer with that.

Comment: yes what you said current In my test case already apply the browser.get()

Comment: @chaitnya i have updated the answer with **third method** where you want to use browser.get() in your test spec. hope it helps.

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XiEkY.png                                                                     I can give one example: browser.get(browser.params.url + '#/note'); So that  i need to get first url from conf js file then first url add with page in my next test case?

Comment: What error are you getting for the above example? It should work with the command that you have shown in the above comment - `browser.get(browser.params.url + '#/note');`. Suppose if your browser url is `http://www.firsturl.com`, then above command will perform `browser.get('http://www.firsturl.com#/note');`

Comment: Please use `protractor conf.js --params.baseUrl "firsturl"` in your command line. `"firsturl"` should be in quotes. I see that you are not using quotes in your command line in your image. You need to use `browser.get(browser.params.url + '#/note');` everytime wherever you want to open the url.

Comment: when run conf js loads firsturl then ineed to load my next test case i need to load browser.get(browser.params.url + '#/note);

Comment: I am not sure if i understand your query @chaitnya. Can you please explain it in a proper way? Are you telling that you want to open different url's in different test cases?

Comment: [![enter image description here][2]][2]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XiEkY.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FjWOJ.png can you sec this images

Comment: Can you give the screenshot where it shows the complete error of your command line? Your image shows nothing about the error.

Comment: thank for your kindness  I can explain scenario I have two URL. when I run  protractor conf js with --params.baseUrl "firsturl" it load that your and then load all other test case related with page are load one by one and hear we don't wont load not related pages this complete scenario ex if runs protractor conf js --params.baseurl "firsturl" it loads related page in don't load not related page of this url

Comment: I am not sure if i still understand your problem. If you want to open a second url then change your url wherever you need to load the second one. If you are saying that u need to open non-related url with the one that is passed, then i guess there is no way you can do that. However you can try setting a new variable in the params object with the new url for non-related pages and set its value in the switch along with other statements.

Answer (score 0):

To use only in one place a URL from json:

```
var jsonFile = require("./path/to/json/relative/to/currentRunFolder");
urlToUse = jsonFile.url; // or however you stored it.
```

use it in any spec, and you can change the json file every run. I hope i understood correctly.

To pass parameters to protractor, use `--params.jsonFile="./path/to/json/relative/to/currentRunFolder"`

and again use it as above using `browser.params.jsonFile`

Comment: thank for your suggestion   " protractor --browser.baseUrl='intg' test\protrator.conf.js" I pass command  like above one but it not work

Comment: what you told everything done but what my question is in command prompt run protractor conf js with URL?

Comment: `--params.url="url"` not browser